# Est-ce que le mot "que" a une nature conditionnelle ? Y a-t-il une règle ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, conditionnel

Je sais que le mot "que" a de différentes natures : adverbe, pronom, conjonction, etc. En général je crois comprendre le sens de ce mot dans des contextes différents, sauf dans certaines phrases que j'ai lues récemment, ou je trouve une sorte de signification conditionnelle, par exemple :

1. Les masques sont exigés dans tous les espaces publics de tous les hôpitaux et bureaux administratifs, ***que** vous soyez en train de marcher ou immobile*.

> J'aurais utilisé : *"**même si** vous êtes en train de marcher ou immobile"*

2. De plus, si vous éprouvez de la difficulté à formuler votre demande ou ***que** vous en êtes à votre première utilisation*, nous vous invitons à communiquer avec nous.

> J'aurais écrit : "**si** vous en êtes à votre première utilisation..."

3. Si vous souhaitez vous établir au Québec de façon permanente et ***que** vous êtes un étudiant étranger*, vous pouvez faire une demande de sélection permanente.

> J'aurais dit : "**si** vous êtes un étudiant étranger..."

Je pense aussi que dans cette construction il y a une relation entre le mot "que" et une conjugaison du verbe être.

Est-ce qu'il y a une règle à propos de cette utilisation du mot, quelle est la fonction de "que" dans ces contextes ?

Je vous serais très reconnaissant si vous pouviez me donner plus d'exemples, d'explications ou de sources où je pourrais m'en informer.

Answer (score 5):

Dans la première phrase, *que* n'y signifie pas  *même si* mais introduit deux possibilités, comme l'anglais *whether ... or ...*.

On retrouve ce *que* dans ces vers fameux de La Fontaine:

> Selon **que** vous serez puissant **ou** misérable
> Les jugements de cour vous rendront blanc ou noir

*Depending on **whether** you are powerful **or** miserable

Court judgments will make you white or black*

Dans les autres phrases, *et/ou **que*** évite la répétition de *et/ou **si*** :

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que):

> **γ**) [Introd. une hypothétique coordonnée] *S'il est seul dans le jardin, et qu'il tombe, il pleure* (Martin du G., *Thib.*, Épil., 1940, p. 841).
> Rem. Bien entendu, c'est seulement en phrase hypothétique que *et si* est remplaçable par *et que* devant la coordonnée. Mais lorsque *si* n'amène pas une supposition, lorsqu'il sert seulement à interroger (interr. indir.) sa reprise s'impose devant la coordonnée: Il se demande s'il tentera de les voir, et s'ils le recevront (Le Bidois 1967, § 1625).